# Cannot find the Always Free Eligible VM Instance when creating it

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I wanted to create a Always Free Eligible VM Instance (VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro) on the Oracle Cloud, but it's not on my list.

And when I check my limit for VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro in
`"Governance > Limits, Quotas and Usage"`, it say 0.

How can I create one? My Home Region is Canada Southeast (Montreal), `ca-montreal-1`.

My account's trial is not over yet. Should I wait till my trial is over to create it?

Comment: Me too. Chat support asked me to create a SR. That doesn't work: 
We apologize for the inconvenience, but this support request cannot be processed. Visit Oracle Support instead.

Comment: Got a response: I would like to inform that the shape VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro is currently unavailable

Answer (score 0):

`VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro` is not available for `ca-montreal-1` at this time (January 2021).

I created a new account in the `Ashburn` region where `VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro` is available.

Comment: Hi, can I create a new account with the same credit card that I used for my old account? If I can't, what can I do to create my new account?

Answer (score -1):

As per the Always Free website, at any time you can have up to the following:

- Two Oracle Autonomous Databases with powerful tools like Oracle Application Express (APEX) and Oracle SQL Developer
- Two Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute VMs; Block, Object, and Archive Storage; Load Balancer and data egress; Monitoring and Notifications

If you already are at capacity for this, then you would not be able to add an additional. Further details of Always Free resources can be found here - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/resourceref.htm

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I can't see the Always Free Eligible VM Instance shape when I want to create one.

Answer (score -1):

The always free provide you with the following

- 2 Compute virtual machines with 1/8 OCPU and 1 GB memory each.
- 2 Block Volumes Storage
- 100 GB total.
- 10 GB Object Storage.
- 10 GB  Archive Storage.
- Resource Manager: managed Terraform.

Focus on the specs of the free one

Comment: Question says I wanted to create a Always Free Eligible VM Instance (VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro) on the Oracle Cloud, but it's not on my list.